# The dimension of $X$ as an affine variety is the same as the dimension as a vector space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb A^n$ be an affine variety that is also a vector space. In my algebraic geometry course we have seen that $X$ is a noetherian topological space so we can define the dimension of $X$ as the supremum over all $n \in \mathbb N$ such that there is a chain
$$\varnothing \subsetneq Y_1 \subsetneq Y_2 \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq Y_n \subseteq X$$
of length $n$ of irreducible closed subsets $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ of $X$. What is the link between this notion of dimension and the dimension of $X$ as a vector space ? It seems that they are equals, because we can always construct a chain like
$$\{0\} \subsetneq \text{Vect }(\{e_1\}) \subsetneq \text{Vect }(\{e_1, e_2\}) \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq \text{Vect }(\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}) = X,$$
but I am not able to write a rigourous argument. Any help?

Comment: It very much depends on the topology of the vector space. For example, $\mathbb{C}^2$ has dimension 2 as a $\mathbb{C}$ vector space but 'topological' dimension 0 in the standard euclidean topology. However, $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$ has dimension two with the zariski topology.

Comment: Yes, I meant Zariski topology!